# How to get the value of reset gate, update gate and current state of GRU at each epoch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I want to get the gate values for the cell state, the reset gate, the update gate of a trained GRU network. According to [this issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1922) I'm able to get weights of kernel, recurrent_kernel and bias for each gate:

```
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from keras.layers import Dense, Embedding, Dropout
from keras.layers import GRU
from keras.datasets import imdb
import keras
import tensorflow as tf
import random as rn
import numpy as np
import math
max_features = 20000
# cut texts after this number of words (among top max_features most common words)
maxlen = 80
batch_size = 128 

print('Loading data...')
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=max_features)
x_train = sequence.pad_sequences(x_train, maxlen=maxlen)
x_test = sequence.pad_sequences(x_test, maxlen=maxlen)

print('Build model...')
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, 100))
model.add(GRU(128))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-5)

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

import keras.backend as K

print('Train...')
epochs = 50

for i in range(epochs):
    print('Epoch', i, '/', epochs)

    model.fit(x_train, y_train,
              batch_size=batch_size,
              epochs=1,
              validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
              #callbacks=[lrate])

    for layer in model.layers:
        if 'GRU' in str(layer):
            #print('states[0] = {}'.format(K.get_value(layer.states[0])))
            #print('states[1] = {}'.format(K.get_value(layer.states[1])))

            weights = layer.get_weights()
            for e in zip(layer.trainable_weights, layer.get_weights()):
                print('Param\n%s:\n%s' % (e[0], e[1]))
```

I want to save the values of each gate to visualize each of them. I could not find any way to find the values of each gate. I am planning to recalculate the gates, however I can't access the states using `layer.states[0] or layer.states[1]`. Is there an easy way to find the gates values at each epoch? Or how can find states values in a GRU cell?

Comment: It's possible but not straightforward. The gates are neither states (like `h`, nor registered parameters (like the `recurrent_kernel`). The easiest way I see is to write your own GRU implementation by extending the existing one to return not just the hidden state but each gate that you want to save. Then, you would call a tf.function where the entire graph is executed after each epoch *again*, but with the gates as the output (similar to [this](https://github.com/philipperemy/keract/blob/228f9201d740f5fb2e2dee539d87a8441b482b17/keract/keract.py#L241).)

Comment: As a side note: If you don't *have* to use Keras standalone, it might be worth switching to tf.keras with TF2 where you can at least infer the values of states easier. Doesn't save you from extending existing or rewriting GRU code, though, as far as I know.

Comment: You need to write your own callback and use get_weights() method